# Python encoding ISO to UTF8

Tags: python, internationalization, encoding

I am trying to read my emails using a Python script (Python 2.5 and PyPy)
Some of my results are not in ASCII and i get strings like this:

> =?ISO-8859-7?B?0OXm7/Dv8d/hIPP07+0gyuno4enx/u3h?='

Is there any way to decode it and convert to utf-8 so that i can process it?
I tried .decode('ISO-8859-7') but i got the same string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import email.header as eh

unicode_data= u''.join(
    str_data.decode(codec or 'ascii')
    for str_data, codec
    in eh.decode_header('=?ISO-8859-7?B?0OXm7/Dv8d/hIPP07+0gyuno4enx/u3h?='))
# unicode_data now is u'Πεζοπορία στον Κιθαιρώνα'
```

You should work with unicode_data here. However, if you (think you) need UTF-8 encoded string, you can:

```
utf8data= unicode_data.encode('utf-8')
```

Update: I changed the `.decode` call to cater for cases where the `codec` is `None` (e.g. `eh.decode_header('plain text')`)

Comment: @Tzotziou: +1 but please don't use `unicodedata` as a "variable name"; it's a module.

Answer (score 1):

Read up on [MIME encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Encoded-Word) and [Base64 encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). The [base64 module](http://docs.python.org/library/base64.html) will be useful.